Why does Facebook show mutual friends on some profiles but not on others?
On Facebook, I encountered an issue where I can see a mutual friend on one person's profile but not on another's. I'm friends with 'A', and 'A' is friends with both 'B' and 'C'. When I view 'B's profile, I can see 4 mutual friends, including 'A'. However, when I check 'C's profile, I can see 5 mutual friends, but 'A' is not listed among them. I've tested this with two different accounts, and the result is the same. Could this be due to privacy settings, or is it a bug? Any insights would be appreciated.
